# Force ASPSessionID to change on login

Tags: asp.net, session, authentication

**How do I get Classic ASP to change the session ID after the user logs in?**

One of our clients ran a security audit against our web site.  So far, we've been able to resolve all the issues they reported.  However, there's one security issue that I'm not sure how to solve, mostly because I've never worked with Classic ASP before.  When the user goes to our web site, classic ASP creates a session and sets a session ID in a `cookie`.  When the user logs in, instead of changing the session ID now that the user has been authenticated, the session ID remains the same.  This is considered a security flaw to use the same session ID after `authentication`

Answer (score 0):

When the user goes to your web site, create cookies and save this cookies in encrypted format in DB table with Data and Time. After verify the cookies set login details newly sessionID.

Hope it will works!